# Is case sensitive search feature available in firefox developer tool debugger panel?

Tags: case-sensitive, firefox-developer-tools

Since Firebug's script panel stopped working following that Firebug is no longer maintained/developed. I needed to switch to Firebug Developer Tools but I cannot find out how we can do a case sensitive search in **debugger panel**.

The built-in search box allows us to search through all the available files though. I really believe that this is an important feature and it might be somewhere there. I tried using Google to find this out with no luck.. Is this feature not yet implemented?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger uses a reasonably common approach to case-sensitivity in searches: if your search string is all lower-case, then it will match anything; but if your search string has an upper-case letter, then it will be case sensitive.

That is, the search string "hello" will match "hello" and "Hello", while the search "Hello" will only match "Hello" and not "hello".

As far as I know there's currently no way to request that a lower-case search string be matched case-sensitively.

Comment: Looks like that is not the case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj5IV.png (2 highlighted areas)

Comment: To be more precise, the search as described only works like this when searching within one source and you need to prefix the search string with `#`. What Binod describes is the search across multiple sources, which always performs a case **in**sensitive search.

Comment: TIL!  That's certainly surprising.  Thanks Sebastian.